# how to set a same DataContext for all UserControls put on a window

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

In MainWindowViewModel.cs.
The constructor is:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel(Window window)
    {
       ...
    }
```

In MainWindow.xaml, I have some UserControls to be included.

```
   <Grid Name="UserControl1">
        <local:UserControl1/>
    </Grid>

   <Grid Name="UserControl2">
        <local:UserControl2/>
    </Grid>

    ...
```

I have tried to set the DataContext for MainWindow hoping that each UserControl will use the same DataContext as MainWindow does, but the result is not as I expect.

```
    private void MainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(this);
        this.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
    }
```

Then I also tried to set the same DataContext for each UserControl, but the result is also wrong, seems only one UserControl can have the correct DataContext in this way.

Finally I removed the DataContext setting in all UserControls but set it here in MainWindow:

```
   <Grid Name="UserControl1">
    <local:UserControl1 Loaded="UserControl1_Loaded"/>
  </Grid>

  <Grid Name="UserControl2">
    <local:UserControl2 Loaded="UserControl2_Loaded"/>
  </Grid>

...

    private void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(this);
        this.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
    }

    private void UserControl2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(this);
        this.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
    }
```

The results are fine. But I think the way I set the DataContext may not be a good  way. Is there a better way to set the DataContext only once and can act on all UserControls? Thanks.

Comment: *"hoping that each UserControl will use the same DataContext as MainWindow does"* - if that doesn't happen, you've certainly set the UserControls' DataContext explicitly in their XAML or code behind. Just remove that.

Comment: It's also a bit strange to have your `Window` as an argument of your MV Class and DataBinding at the same time. It may lead to a lot of confusion... something like Clemens suggested.

Comment: Can't you just set it explicitly in UserControl like `DataContext = "{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"`?

Comment: I wrote mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(Application.Current.MainWindow); in UserControl2 but didn't write this.DataContext=mainWindowViewModel; Is it also considered as setting the DataContext? @Clemens

Comment: As said, do not set DataContext at all in a UserControl's XAML or code behind. The UserControl will then inherit the DataContext of the MainWindow.

Comment: Definitly, now what are you doing is just setting DataContext of MainWindow 3 times

Comment: Ok, thanks. @Clemens

Comment: If you totally need to make this in UserControl.Loaded function you could add `(x as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;` But I would recomed you to make this in Xaml of userControl

Comment: @sTrenat It is not necessary to set a UserControl's DataContext *at all*, neither in code nor in XAML. The DataContext will automatically be inherited by the UserControls.

Comment: It should be, but i don't know the context of where is he setting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need *any* code to set the DataContext of your UserControls, because the value of the MainWindow's DataContext is automatically passed to all of its child elements by [dependency property value inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/property-value-inheritance).

This will however only work if the UserControls do not set their own DataContext, by something like

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

in their XAML, or

```
this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

in their code behind. Remove all such assignments.